# Workbook sheet last cell run error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,
Can anybody help me why stops this code with error message (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range)?

The code snippet:

```
CollectFileName = "C:\Users\g\Documents\CAFM\VBS\access.xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open (CollectFileName)
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False

LastDayRow = Workbooks(CollectFileName).Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Is the sheet that you're trying to look at actually called '1' or is it called 'Sheet 1'. That would explain why it thinks it's out of range, if the name is incorrect. You are calling something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Gallus It does exist. `1` is the index number of the Sheets collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a workbook to specify the Sheet, you should also do the same with `Rows.Count` (and others, like `Cells()`, `, Columns()`,`Rows()`, etc.):

`LastDayRow = Workbooks(CollectFileName).Sheets(1).Range("B" & Workbooks(CollectFileName).Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

or

```
CollectFileName = "C:\Users\g\Documents\CAFM\VBS\access.xlsx"
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CollectFileName)

With wb.Sheets(1)
    lastDayRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: FWIW - Though this will fix the problem, the subscript out of range was due to the OP passing the full string `"C:\Users\g\Documents\CAFM\VBS\access.xlsx"` into the `WorkBooks` instead of just `"access.xlsx"`.  By assigning the variable `wb` this is avoided.  The `With` block is an added "Good Practice".

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You are right. The "wb" is the solution. Thank you all for your help.